# getting the content from an html form POST using TCPSocket

Tags: ruby, sockets, post, tcpsocket

using the 'gets' method repeatedly on a TCPSocket object, I receive the following output

```
POST /targetPage.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:7125
...
...
...
Keep-Alive: 115
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:7125/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 45
```

If I use .gets again everything hangs, how would I get this 'content' of length 45?  Can I get this from my TCPSocket object or do I have to use something else?

Comment: you might find it easier to use `Net::HTTP` or `Mechanize` instead of doing this by hand.  Net::HTTP is in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets` reads a line, so it will block until the connection times out or it reads a newline character.  You should use the `read` method, which reads a given number of bytes (which is very conveniently provided in the Content-Length header).

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for. Reading through ruby-doc I don't see the method 'read', how could I have found this out? spare asking stack overflow..

Comment: @Matthew: yes, it's confusing to read the documentation at first.  Note that the `Socket` class is a subclass of `BasicClass`, which is in turn a subclass of `IO` (this is listed in the documentation under the 'Parent' field for each class).  The `IO` class has the `read` method.

Comment: oops, I meant that `Socket` is a subclass of `BasicSocket`, not `BasicClass`

Answer (score 0):

Include the header:

Connection: close

to the header. This will prevent the hanging before actually reading the body of the request.